# How to rotate camera recorded video?

Tags: python, opencv, video-capture, face-detection

I am trying to detect faces in a camera recorded video. When i did it with webcam video, it's working fine. But, with camera recorded video, the video gets rotated by -90 degree. Please suggest me, how do I get the actual video output for face detection?

```
import cv2
import sys

cascPath = sys.argv[1]
faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('C:/Users/HP/Anaconda2/pkgs/opencv-3.2.0-np112py27_204/Library/etc/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')

#video_capture = cv2.videoCapture(0)
video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture('C:/Users/HP/sample1.mp4')
w=int(video_capture.get(3))
h=int(video_capture.get(4))

#output = cv2.VideoWriter('output_1.avi',cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('M','J','P','G'), 60,frameSize = (w,h))

while True:

    ret, frame = video_capture.read()
    frame = rotateImage(frame,90)

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5) 

    # Draw a rectangle around the faces
    for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
    #cv2.imshow('face',i)

    #output.write(frame)

    cv2.imshow('Video', frame)

        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break

    video_capture.release()
    output.release()

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In cv2 you can use the cv2.rotate function to rotate image as per your requirement

```
rotated=cv2.rotate(img, cv2.ROTATE_90_CLOCKWISE)
```

Answer (score 1):

for rotating video you can use cv2.flip(), this method take 3 Args and one of them is the rotating code(0,1,-1) you can check this link for more details:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-opencv-cv2-flip-method/